# Reducer return undefined in data update

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, reducers

I am trying to create a reducer to delete object after an action has invoked, but i cant update and save the new object inside my data

**Reducer:**

```
export default function deleteCard(state = INITIAL_STATE, action: any) {
  if (action.type === 'DELETE_CARD') {
    return state.data.filter((card: Card) => card.cardId !== action.id)
  } else {
    return state
  }
}
```

**Action deleteCard**

```
export const deleteCardAction = (id: number) => {
  return {
    type: 'DELETE_CARD',
    id: id
  }
}
```

**function handleDeleteCard() <- call the action**

```
 const cards = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => state.createCard.data);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function handleDeleteCard() {
    cards.map(({ cardId }: Card) => {     
      if (cardId === props.activeCard ) {
        dispatch(deleteCardAction(cardId))
      }
    })
  }
```

**`Initial State:`**

```
  export const INITIAL_STATE = {
  activeCard: 0,
  data: [
    {
      cardId: 0,
      cardName: 'Credit card',
      cardUsername: 'Vanzo',
      cardNumber: '1234 1234 1234 1234',
      hideCardNumber: false,
    },
  ]
}
```

**Following error when i try to update:**

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.data.filter')
```

Comment: How are you using the `deleteCard` reducer? It appears it's not receiving the state, but we can't know why without seeing how you're using it.

Comment: I've updated with the part of code that executes the reducer

Comment: You need to return the whole state in each reducer case.  You are just returning the filtered state.data array so that now becomes the state.

Comment: @PORMAZION Thanks, the answer given below should fix the issue, it's definitely good advice.

Answer (score 1):

For updating the state you need to return the whole state from reducer something like this:

```
export default function deleteCard(state = INITIAL_STATE, action: any) {
  if (action.type === 'DELETE_CARD') {
    return {
        ...state,
        data: state.data.filter((card: Card) => card.cardId !== action.id)
    }
  } else {
    return state
  }
}
```